# Save OS .vhd for later installation

Tags: virtualhost, virtual-machines, vhd

One of my system administrator had an virtual machine (of Win 7 OS) that we used as a testing OS.

Now if we need to have a fresh machine, she used to give that very quickly w/o installing the OS again. Somehow she used to have a saved .vhd or something and that she used to load into some software  - Not sure how and what she used to do.

Do you have any idea. I know my question is very vague, hence let me know if I'm unclear about what I want to know.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you told is which virtualization environment you're using.

Comment: @lain: We used to have MS Virtual PC 2007

Comment: @lain: I assume this info is sufficient

Comment: It is, but if you do not know how to copy/paste a file, maybe you should ask someone. "how she used to do it" runs down into a trivial file copy operations.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can have a copy of a .vhd that you just redeploy, or you can use snapshots. Either of these things sound like what you're talking about.

Comment: +1. That is pretty much what I do - i have a differential vhdx that is sysprepped and gets copiped for a new VM.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.  Simply copying the .vhd file from a stored/template location to another is the most common method.  Depending on your SAN configuration you may also be able to perform this operation in a similar fashion.